# jQuery datePicker does not popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

After clicking on input field the datepicker does not popup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         var sds = document.getElementsByClassName("f_sd");
         for(var i = 0; i < sds.length; i ++){
                sds[i].id = i+":sd";
                 var id = "#"+i+":sd";
                 $(id).datepicker();
         }
});
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Which datepicker do you use?

Comment: No there is no an error message.

Comment: What datepicker script are you using? Create a working demo on jsfiddle.net ASAP ;-) ?

Comment: `id` attributes may not start with a number. Try changing that to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here

```
sds[i].id = i+":sd";
```

control id should not contain `:`

JSFiddle without `:` in control id http://jsfiddle.net/QsgNF/1/

JSFiddle with `:` in control id http://jsfiddle.net/QsgNF/2/

You can see that the first fiddle without `:` is giving desired output where as the second fiddle is failing.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it very strange way, try this code

```
$(function(){
  $('.f_sd').datepicker();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kaVLH/

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible datepicker is coming but you cant see that because of Z-index,

i have same issue so i increase z-index of datepicker component,

hope this will help you.

Comment: No datepicker does not appear, z-index is clear.